# Truss analysis how to calculate for a single beam?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statics, structural-beam

[image]
Suppose I want to calculate the tension/compression force only in 4.

Is there an easier way to calculate it or do I have to calculate everything with the joint method?

I don't immediately see zero-force members.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider the balance of a small section of the truss.

[image: skt]

You have 3 unknown forces (three member tensions, shown in red) and 3 equations (sum of forces & moments are zero). The reaction forces (shown in blue) are considered known for a statically determinant problem.